# how to join equivalent classes from 2 different ontologies in Protegé?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, foaf

I'm new in Protegé. I've created a new Ontology and I would like to merge the Person class with Person class in foaf.

How can I do that? I have tried with Equivalent to but I don't see both ontologies linked  in http://www.visualdataweb.de/webvowl

[Foaf and mine ontologies separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRRWG.png)

Comment: I think you should be more specific about what you understand by "merge" here. Why making the two classes equivalent is not sufficient?

Comment: When I say merge, I mean that 2 classes are equivalent in the visual ontology (showed in VisualDataWeb.de)

Comment: I've added a picture showing both ontologies separated. They should be joined(or merged) by Person class.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I realized that Person class in my ontology is a subclass in foaf antology.

So, I've added as a subclass in Protegé and it worked :)